# Does the choice of flattening matter in conv nets and what flattening technique should I use?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, conv-neural-network

For almost all conv net architectures you need to flatten the output from the last conv layer to the linear layer.

The output from the conv layer is typically a batch of "processed images" $T$, with dimensions $(C, W, H)$

We flatten this into a single vector $V \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

However, as you can imagine there are many many many ways to flatten a tensor into a vector...

1. Order all entries of this tensor $T$, then sequentially put them into a list. Or put them in a list but with reverse indexing order
2. Strip this tensor column by column, and stack them up. (Alternatively do the same as above with rows)
3. Iteratively take the mean value along each dimension until it is a vector
4. Iteratively take the max value of every dimension until it is a vector

ad Infinium ...

So what choice of flattening technique should I use and why?